# SSIS Data Conversion Error: Overflow Issue in Automated Job Execution

Tags: excel, ssis, data-conversion

I'm encountering an issue with data conversion in my SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package. When I execute the package manually, everything works fine. However, when I run it in an automated job, I encounter an error specifically related to converting from double float to numeric data types.
This problem occurs specifically with values containing commas in my Excel data source
The error message states: 'Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the type used by the data conversion transform'.

How can I address this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wonder if either the Excel file is different between your manual run and the job run (maybe one's dev while the other prod). Or maybe the DB table you're trying to insert to is different between dev and prod, like the column in question is defined differently.